# Using "or" in pandas dataframe to search for strings

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I would like to do this:

```
df[(df["Class"] == 'Class1' or  'Class2')]
```

i.e. find rows with class 1 or 2, but can't find the correct syntax in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better is use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df[df["Class"].isin(['Class1','Class2'])]
```

Or use `|` for bitwise `or` with `()` because priority precedence of operators with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df[(df["Class"] == 'Class1') |  (df["Class"] == 'Class2')]
```

Another solutions with [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df.query("Class == ['Class1', 'Class2']")
```

Or:

```
df.query("Class == 'Class1' |  Class == 'Class2'")
#here working or too
#df = df.query("Class == 'Class1' or  Class == 'Class2'")
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the options

```
df[(df["Class"] == 'Class1') |  (df["Class"] =='Class2')]
```

or

```
df[df["Class"].isin(['Class1','Class2'])]
```